# Is there any universal solution for scrolling both UITextView and UITextField above the keyboard on screen

Tags: ios, iphone, uitextfield, uitextview

How to scroll UITextField, UITextview in UITableView or in UIViewController when keyboard appears on the screen.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1126726/how-to-make-a-uitextfield-move-up-when-keyboard-is-present

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/StringsTextFonts/Conceptual/TextAndWebiPhoneOS/KeyboardManagement/KeyboardManagement.html look this also

Answer (score 3):

I'm using [IQKeyboardManager](https://github.com/hackiftekhar/IQKeyboardManager). In general it's as easy as adding `[IQKeyBoardManager installKeyboardManager];` to a `viewDidLoad` method.

Answer (score 1):

Just handle the `textView`/`textField` delegate methods and adjust your view frame accordingly.

You can also add all the controls inside a scroll view and then scroll up/down within the following delegate methods

```
-(void)textFieldDidBeginEditing:(UITextField *)textField
{
    scrollView.frame = CGRectMake(scrollView.frame.origin.x,
                                  scrollView.frame.origin.y,
                                  scrollView.frame.size.width,
                                  scrollView.frame.size.height - 215 + dynamicHeight);
}

-(void)textFieldDidEndEditing:(UITextField *)textField
{
    scrollView.frame = CGRectMake(scrollView.frame.origin.x,
                                  scrollView.frame.origin.y,
                                  scrollView.frame.size.width,
                                  scrollView.frame.size.height + 215 - dynamicHeight);
}
```

You can also set notification to fire the `-keyboardWillShow` and `-keyboardWillHide` methods.

There are these 3rd party library availabe on github.
Just google it and you will find loads of them.

https://github.com/michaeltyson/TPKeyboardAvoiding